# Replace parentheses and spaces in filenames with underscore

Tags: linux, shell

I use this line to remove blank spaces on folder name

```
find /tmp/ -depth -name "* *" -execdir rename 's/ /_/g' "{}" \;
```

Is there a way to remove SPACES and PARENTHESES from filename and put underscore?

For example, I have:

```
|-- a_dir
|   `-- (1) file with spaces and parentheses.pdf
`-- b_dir
    |-- (43) another file with spaces (1).pdf
    `-- (132) yet another file with spaces (3343).pdf
```

Must become

```
|-- a_dir
|   `-- 1_file_with_spaces_and_parentheses.pdf
`-- b_dir
    |-- 43_another_file_with_spaces_1.pdf
    `-- 132_yet_another_file_with_spaces_3343.pdf
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
find /tmp/ -depth -name "*[ ()]*" -execdir rename 's/[ )]/_/g; s/\(//g' "{}" \;
```

Comment: I think you meant to have the closing paren in the second expression.  That keeps files with the last character before the . extension from having a funny looking trailing underscore

Comment: doesn't work on mac because of `rename`; I think it needs to be actively installed, at the very least

Comment: Yes it needs to be installed separately. I am also on OSX and using rename

Comment: this works only with the ubuntu [rename package] (https://salsa.debian.org/perl-team/modules/packages/rename) CentOS also has a rename package but works quite to this, and hence this command does not work in CentOS

Comment: This requires `rename` perl utility.